# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de las celdas seleccionadas en WPF y MVVM?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, mvvm

soy bastante nuevo en WPF y en programación en general y quisiera saber cómo obtener el valor de unas celdas seleccionadas en un tabla en WPF.

En internet la mayoria de los ejemplos son de DataGridView o sin usar MVVM, no sé si tego que añadir `template` o un `trigger` o algo parecido ya que en Internet he visto algo así pero no me queda claro nada; en el caso de que supieran cómo hacerlo les dejo mi código para que puedan verlo y añadir la parte de código faltante.

```
<UserControl x:Class="Tgw.SouthHub.UI.Administration.Views.WareHouseMapView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Tgw.SouthHub.UI.Administration.Views"
         xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
         xmlns:conv="clr-namespace:Tgw.SouthHub.UI.Administration.Views.Converters"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<UserControl.Resources>

  <Style x:Key="NameCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
    <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
  </Style>

</UserControl.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <Button Height="50" Width="100" Command="{Binding UpdateAisleOne}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Pasillo 1</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="100" Command="{Binding UpdateAisleTwo}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Pasillo 2</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="150" Command="{Binding UpdateConventional}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Convencional</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="150" Command="{Binding bloqCell_Click}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Bloq Celda</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="150" Command="{Binding habiCell_Click}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Habi Celda</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="150" Command="{Binding cmdMapInventory_Click}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Inventariar</Button>
          <Button Height="50" Width="150" Command="{Binding cmdMapCancelReservation_Click}" Margin="10,10,10,10">Cencelar Reserva</Button>
        </StackPanel>
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="10,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentAisle}" MinRowHeight="9"
                FontSize="9"  IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Extended" CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}" CurrentCell="{Binding CeldaSeleccionada, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
      </DataGrid>
      <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Margin="10,10,10,10" ItemsSource="{Binding ContentAisle2}" MinRowHeight="9"
                FontSize="9"  IsReadOnly="True" SelectionUnit="Cell" SelectionMode="Extended" CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}">
      </DataGrid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

En este momento lo único que quiero hacer es obtener el valor de esas celdas y cuando se pulse el botón `BloqCell` se obtendría ese valor y yo trabajaría con él para cambiar los estados de las celdas en mi base de datos. Os dejo el código de cómo he creado el método que dipara el evento. Está vacío, obviamente, porque no sé obtener este valor de las celdas selccionadas.

```
        private DataGridCellInfo celdaSeleccionada;

private ICommand _bloq_Cell;
    public ICommand bloqCell_Click
    {
        get
        {
            return _bloq_Cell ?? (_bloq_Cell = new CommandHandler((object param) => bloqCell(), true));
        }
    }

    private void bloqCell()
    {
       var celda = GetDataGridCell(celdaSeleccionada);
    }

    public DataGridCellInfo CeldaSeleccionada
    {
        get
        {
            return this.celdaSeleccionada;
        }
        set
        {
            this.celdaSeleccionada = value;
            this.NotifyOfPropertyChange("CeldaSeleccionada");
        }
    }

    public DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
    {
        var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
        if (cellContent != null)
            return (DataGridCell)cellContent.Parent;

        return null;
    }
```

El ultimo metodo al hacer debug se ve como cellinfo.Item esta vacio y no puede continuar.

Comment: Si usas mvvm, en principio lo unico que debes hacer es un binding de la propiedad `CurrentCell` de `Datagrid` a una propiedad de tu ViewModel de tipo `DataGridCellInfo`

Comment: Podrias ponerme un ejemplo en codigo.Gracias

Comment: @Pikoh Gracias por intentar ayudarme. Aun asi aunque le quite la propiedad al segundo Grid sigue dando fallo diciendo que esta vacio, parece que cuando se seleciona una celda el evento de CurrentCell no inserta ningun dato en el Binding de CEldaSeleccionada.

Comment: Gracias, a ver si obtenemos la solucion a mi problema. :)

Comment: Una cosa...si pones un punto de depuracion en el setter de la propiedad CeldaSeleccionada, se dispara al seleccionar una celda?

Comment: Y otra, veo que tienes `this.NotifyOfPropertyChange("CellInfo");`, debería ser `this.NotifyOfPropertyChange("CeldaSelecionada");`

Comment: Cierto tanto copiar pegar, siempre se te escapa algo. voy a probar

Comment: @Pikoh Al poner el punto hay veo que cada vez que seleciono una celda si se asigna, eso lo hemos arreglado, ahora me arroja otro error en la linea del metodo GetDataGridCell. Cuado pulso el boton me salta hay el eror en concreto cuado se asigna valor a la variable cellContent. Este es el NullReferenceException An exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Tgw.SouthHub.UI.Administration.ViewModels.dll but was not handled in user code

Comment: Eso es posiblemente porque `Item`es null. La verdad es que ese código lo obtuve de una pregunta de [so] como ya dije. Haz una cosa. Pon un punto de depuración en ese método y examina las propiedades de `cellInfo` a ver que devuelve

Comment: @Pikoh Creo que he descubierto el problema, e visto que el valor es true cuando pincho una celda y el valor se queda a true con lo cual la celdaSelecionada si que recibe y se queda asignado el valor, pero e el momento en el que pincho en el boton de bloqCell, celda seleccionada pierde el valor,  por que vuelve a llamarse solo el metodo del Binding y le asigna un valor vacio, no entiendo por que si pulso el boton bloq vuelve a llamar a este metodo de asignarle el valor

Comment: Probablemente porque deja de estar seleccionada la celda. Lo que puedes hacer es comprobar en el setter si value==null, y en ese caso no asignar el valor

Comment: @Pikoh En todos los casos siempre es un valor null, aunque seleccione una celda sigue siendo null, no asigna el valor de la celda con  contentCell,si que hace un set pero siempre es null. Algo estamos haciendo mal XD

Comment: En cuanto tenga un poco de tiempo, trataré de crear un [mcve] para ver que puede estar pasando. Si,de todas maneras puedes crear algo tu, mejor :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debes añadir un binding de la propiedad `CurrentCell` de `Datagrid` a una propiedad de tu `ViewModel` de tipo `DataGridCellInfo`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
         Margin="10,10,10,10" 
         ItemsSource="{Binding ContentAisle}" 
         MinRowHeight="9"
         FontSize="9"  
         IsReadOnly="True" 
         SelectionUnit="Cell" 
         SelectionMode="Extended" 
         CellStyle="{StaticResource NameCellStyle}"
         CurrentCell="{Binding CeldaSeleccionada, Mode=OneWayToSource}"/>
```

En tu ViewModel:

```
private DataGridCellInfo _celdaSeleccionada;
public DataGridCellInfo CeldaSeleccionada
{
    get { return _celdaSeleccionada; }
    set
    {
        _celdaSeleccionada= value;
        OnPropertyChanged("CeldaSeleccionada");
    }
}
```

Obtener la celda a partir del `DataGridCellInfo` requiere un poco de trabajo. Este método (obtenido de [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17066695/579895)) lo hace:

```
public DataGridCell GetDataGridCell(DataGridCellInfo cellInfo)
{
    var cellContent = cellInfo.Column.GetCellContent(cellInfo.Item);
    if (cellContent != null)
        return (DataGridCell) cellContent.Parent;

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Entendo lo que me quieres decir, hago lo que me dijistes pero no funciona me devuelve un valor vacio, no entiendo por que. Edito mi codigo para que veas com lo hice a ver si hay algun fallo.